# C# DynamicData and WhenPropertyChanged - skip initial value when collection is initialized

Tags: c#, dynamic-data, reactiveui

I have a simple code:

```
class ItemViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private string _name;
    private string _value;

    public ItemViewModel(string name, string value)
    {
        _name = name;
        _value = value;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _name, value);
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _value, value);
    }
}

IObservable<IChangeSet<ItemViewModel>> changeSet = CreateChangeSet();
```

I want to react to any change of the `Value` property in any of the objects in change set, and do something with new value. I tried like this:

```
changeSet 
    .WhenPropertyChanged(x => x.Value)
    .DistinctUntilChanged()
    .Subscribe(value =>
    {
         // do sth with value
    });
```

but `WhenPropertyChanged` provides initial value for each item when collection is initialized and I want to avoid that. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to avoid. Is it a) invoking the subscriber several times when many items are changed at once or b) the subscriber get the initial value instead of the changed value?

Comment: It's option b) which I want to avoid.

Comment: Why can't you do this?
    
    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => if(value != _value) this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _value, value);
    }

The code above tells you: If the value is different from the previous one, then set the value, otherwise just ignore it.

Comment: @Bruno it doesn't matter, and additionally `DistinctUntilChanged` does the same job as `if value != value`. The behavior I described results from using `WhenPropertyChanged` - it provides initial value when collection is initialized. And I want to avoid it somehow.

Comment: There are ways to do that, one would be:  you could use a static field to check whether a property (Value) has been set for the first time (which I do not recommend), however, it's better to understand WHY do you want to do that, perhaps we can come with a better solution.

Comment: Ok so I have a collection of `ItemViewModel` which is bind to a ListView and user can edit every item Value using textbox. After each Value update I must call some API and pass new value. With the sample code in original post, when the ChangeSet is initialized it calls subscriber for each item in the collection, because that's how `WhenPropertyChanged` works. So this would make a lot of unnecessary requests to API and I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the notifyOnInitialValue parameter to false. It's true by default. I just tried in a sandbox console app as a sanity check, and it does indeed work as expected.

```
changeSet
    .WhenPropertyChanged(x => x.Value, notifyOnInitialValue: false)
```

Source: https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData/blob/63960b0fa7bd0362c40e137498cd0014ba02f3dc/src/DynamicData/Binding/NotifyPropertyChangedEx.cs#L59